# Only 2 of my 3 JComponents showing on my JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jcomponent

I am making a game in java and I can't add more than jcomponents to my jframe.  I have already tried to add it to a jpanel and to a container. I have even tried to make the Border class extend JPanel instead of JComponent.  Thank you in advance.

PICTURE OF PROBLEM

[image]

***Main Class***

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class game implements KeyListener {
public static JFrame window = new JFrame("Escape");
public static int velX = 0, velY = 0, count = 0;
public static Boolean paused = false, leftLock = false;
public Player player, playerTwo;
public static Movement playerMove;
public static Collision coll;
public static Area playerArea, playerTwoArea;
public Border b;

game() {
    player = new Player();
    playerTwo = new Player();
    b = new Border(10,10);
    window.setSize(1000, 500);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.addKeyListener(this);
    window.add(new Border(0,0));
    window.add(new Border(200,200));
    window.add(new Border(400,400));
    window.setVisible(true);
    playerMove = new Movement();
    coll = new Collision();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new game();
    }
}
```

***My Border Class***

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Border extends JComponent {
    private int x, y;

Border(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOvel(x,y,50,50);
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see where you specify layout managers... are you using a null layout?

Comment: yes i am using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are drawing arbitrary (and many) shapes, you probably shouldn't be using JComponents for them. I'd just place one JPanel in your window, override the paintComponents method on it, and do all your drawing for all your Circles in that one method.

Comment: how would i move the players and enemys if i did it that way? I plan on making it multiplayer.

Comment: I don't just want to draw a circle and keep it there.